# Serie in dataframe column into multiples column Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an issue when training a simple model, my problem is in the preparation of the data.

I have this data frame :
[image]

For more precision, my first line of the df is :

```
ma_df.loc[0].iloc[1]
[array([ 2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  3.,  1.,  5., 26.,  5.,  3.,
         3.,  5.,  4.,  0.,  4.,  2.,  6., 17.,  7.,  3.,  1.,  4.,  1.,
         2.,  7.,  4.,  6.,  5.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  4.,  1.,  7.,  3.,  1.,
         1.,  6.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  6.,  4.,  6.,  0.,  5.,  7.,  0.,  0.,
         6.,  1.,  1.,  2., 17.,  3.,  1., 15.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  3., 10.,
         9.,  6.,  6.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  8.,  4.,  8.,  3.,
         5., 12.,  1.,  1.,  1., 14.,  1.,  4.,  7.,  8.,  0.,  4.,  2.,
         4.,  7.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  5.]),
 array([10.,  5.,  3.,  6.,  2.,  3., 13.,  2., 16.,  2.,  0.,  4.,  3.,
         4.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  6.,  2.,  4.,  7.,  6.,
         4., 16.,  8.,  5.,  2., 10.,  6.,  1.,  0.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,
        10.,  4.,  3.,  6.,  5.,  3.,  8.,  3.,  6., 10.,  2.,  4.,  8.,
        23.,  0.,  1.,  7.,  1.,  6., 11.,  5.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  7.,  6.,
         5., 10.,  1.,  6.,  2.,  4.,  3.,  1.,  4.,  2., 11., 16., 12.,
         2.,  0.,  4.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  7.,  2.,  7.,  2.,  4.,  1.,  4.,
         6., 12.,  1.,  4.,  7.,  4.,  7.,  7.,  0.]),
...
```

And I want to train a model with :

```
X = np.array(ma_df['Histogram'])
y = ma_df['Classes']
y = Y.to_numpy()
```

This code :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)
```

throw the following error :

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [20, 400]
```

I don't understand how to prepare my data frame before the train_test_split to not have any shape issue ? Maybe by splitting the Histogram column but I don't know how ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you let me know what is the output to X.shape and y.shape ? , will help in better understanding the problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Here are the shape : Size of X : (20,) Size of y : (20,)

Comment: Hey, so it looks like the sizes are similar. The problem may occour in the data set post split. The problem can be due to test_size = 0.1 , there can be missing mappings between X_test and y_test. Please check all the different sizes. You have only 20 data points, splitting into train and test data does not make much sense due to the fact that you may get really biased results on the test data.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think is possible to split the df to have on row one histogram associate to a classe (having multiple ligne for dog class ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work, (I assumed you may have following data where each Histogram value contains a list of values with same shape)
Assumed data:

```
    Classes Histogram
0   class1  [[h11, h12, h13]]
1   class2  [[h21, h22, h23]]
2   class3  [[h31, h32, h33]]
```

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Assumed data
data = {
    'Classes':['class1','class2','class3'],
    'Histogram':[[['h11','h12','h13']],[['h21','h22','h23']],[['h31','h32','h33']]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Getting Histogram values to form columns
spl = df['Histogram'].explode().apply(pd.Series)

#Joining Histogram values to original dataframe
df = df.join(spl).drop('Histogram',axis=1)

#Specifying X and y features 
X = df.iloc[:,1:]
y = df['Classes']

#Splitting data into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)
```